# vb.net: why is this starting at 0?

Tags: vb.net

```
    Dim myDelims As String() = New String() {"<beginning of record>"}
    Dim split1 As String() = temp_string.Split(myDelims, StringSplitOptions.None)

    For Each s As String In split1
        If InStr(s, lot__no) Then
```

for some reason, the first s in split1 is giving a value of "". there's nothing in it. why is it starting ONE before the first element?

Comment: no need to ask the same question again:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1640279/vb-net-in-which-case-would-this-return-0

Comment: If temp_string starts with "<beginning of record>", then that would be the expected result, wouldn't it?

Comment: This is not the same question. It's asking a different thing.

Comment: you're right..my lazy eyes didnt notice

Comment: "why is it starting ONE before the first element" - what do you mean by this and the title of the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries` to filter out empty strings.

By default, the `String.Split` method will *split* the string by the delimiter. If the string starts with the delimiter, it's basically composed of an empty string, the delimiter, and the remaining part of the string.

```
Dim s = "!Hello!World!"
Dim delimiters = {"!"}
Dim arr = s.Split(delimiters, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
Array.ForEach(arr, AddressOf Console.WriteLine) ' // Prints out the result
```

In this example, `arr` will contain two elements, "Hello" and "World". Without `RemoveEmptyEntires`, it would have contained four elements, "", "Hello", "World", and "".